# Castle Windsor Typed Factory Facility

Tags: castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

When **_fwf.GetFileWatcher** is called, always MailWatcher is returning. How can I return FileWatcher class with typed factory facility? I tried code block as below but this gets always the first component.

Also I tried DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector but i can't get a result.

```
 public interface IWatcher : IDisposable
{
    void StartWatching();
}

public class MailWatcher : IWatcher
{

    public void StartWatching()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mail watcher");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

 public class FileWatcher : IWatcher
{
    public void StartWatching()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File watcher");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IFileWatcherFactory : IDisposable
{
    IWatcher GetWatcher(string path);
    void Destroy(IWatcher fw);
}

 public class Bootstrapper
{
    private static WindsorContainer _container;
    private static IFileWatcherFactory _fwf;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        _container.Register(Component.For<IWatcher>().ImplementedBy<MailWatcher>().LifeStyle.Transient);
        _container.Register(Component.For<IWatcher>().ImplementedBy<FileWatcher>().LifeStyle.Transient);

        _container.Register(Component.For<IFileWatcherFactory>().AsFactory(x => x.SelectedWith(new FileWatcherSelector())));

        _fwf = _container.Resolve<IFileWatcherFactory>();
        strong textvar fw = _fwf.GetFileWatcher("file", 20); 
        fw.StartWatching();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does FileWatcherSelector look like?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... in order to call GetFileWatcher("file", 20) your IFileWatcherFactory should include that methods/signature and by nameconvetion will resolve/create an instance of FileWatcher that should have those 2 params within its own constructor. I guess you are doing some wrong magics into FileWatcherSelector.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this, using the TypedFactoryFacility, to dictate which type the Factory will create if this varies, you can use the Get[Name] convention, where your interface will have a create method for each implementation type.

```
public class MailWatcher : IWatcher
{

    public void StartWatching()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mail watcher");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class FileWatcher : IWatcher
{
    public void StartWatching()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File watcher");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IFileWatcherFactory : IDisposable
{
    IWatcher GetMailWatcher(string path);
    IWatcher GetFileWatcher(string path);
    void Destroy(IWatcher fw);
}

public class Bootstrapper
{
    private static WindsorContainer _container;
    private static IFileWatcherFactory _fwf;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        _container.Register(Component.For<IWatcher>().ImplementedBy<MailWatcher>().Named("MailWatcher").LifeStyle.Transient);
        _container.Register(Component.For<IWatcher>().ImplementedBy<FileWatcher>().Named("FileWatcher").LifeStyle.Transient);

        _container.Register(Component.For<IFileWatcherFactory>().AsFactory());

        _fwf = _container.Resolve<IFileWatcherFactory>();
        var fw = _fwf.GetFileWatcher("file", 20); 
        fw.StartWatching();
    }
}
```

For more information, please refer to :

http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx#Get_methods_lookup_components_by_name_4